# Showing the injective map from $\mathfrak{g}$ to $U(\mathfrak{g})$.

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

From Theorem 9.7 in *Lie groups, Lie algebras, and representations* written by Hall,

the linear map $ i : \mathfrak{g} \rightarrow U(\mathfrak{g})$ is defined by

1. For all $X$, $Y \in \mathfrak{g}$, $i([X,Y])=i(X)i(Y)-i(Y)i(X)$.
2. $U(\mathfrak{g})$ is generated by $\{i(X) : X \in \mathfrak{g}\}$.
3. If $\mathcal{A}$ is an associative algebra with identity and $j: \mathfrak{g} \rightarrow \mathcal{A}$ is a linear map such that 
   $$ j([X,Y])=j(X)j(Y)-j(Y)j(X)$$
   for all $X$, $Y \in \mathfrak{g}$. Then there exists  a unique algebra homomorphism $\phi : U(\mathfrak{g}) \rightarrow \mathcal{A}$ such that
   $\phi(1)=1$ and such that $\phi(i(X))=j(X)$ for all $X\in\mathfrak{g}$.

where $\mathfrak{g}$ is any Lie algebra and $U(\mathfrak{g})$ is an associative algebra with identity.

The question is here. How can I show the linear map $i$ is injective when $\mathfrak{g} \subset Mat_n(\mathbb{C})$ without Poincare-Birkhoff-Witt theorem ?

In order to show, I first assume that $i(X)=i(Y)$ and so I induced
$$ i([X,Y])=i(X)i(Y)-i(Y)i(X)=0$$ 
implies that $[X,Y]=XY-YX=0$ from linearity by condition 1.
However, I am stuck. How can I prove that $X=Y$ ?

Comment: That approach won't work, as for any $X$ there's usually many elements $Y\neq X$ with $[X,Y]=0$.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Yes. I have suffered from that fact. I considered there is something in condition but it may be not. Then, how can I show that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one information you have about your $\mathfrak{g}$ is that it is contained in some $M_n(\Bbb C)$, so we should use that somehow. Well, $M_n(\Bbb C)$ is an associative algebra with unit, and the inclusion can be written fancier as an injective (!) map

$$j: \mathfrak{g} \hookrightarrow \mathcal A := M_n(\Bbb C).$$

Now use property 3 to conclude that $i$ must be injective.